# Showing video from blobstorage

Tags: html, azure, azure-blob-storage

I want to show a video stored in Azure blobstorage.

```
<video ng-click="showIntroVideo()" controls>
<source src="http://dev.blob.core.windows.net/documents/Intro.mp4" type="video/mp4">
```

The Container is set to public.
The video dont show or play.
What am I missing?

The project is a MVC 4.5 with a bootstrap front end. I also use angular.

Comment: Will it be possible to share the actual URL of the blob?

Comment: see if this applies to you  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19655868/streaming-video-from-azure-blob-storage

Comment: I was inclined to say check the container ACL but you already mentioned that it is public so that is not the issue (but you may want to check that again). Another thing is the `Content-Type` property of the blob. What I have seen (at least with images) is that some browsers don't display the images if the content type is not set properly. I wanted to check it out myself by exploring the blob through a browser and check the content type in response. That's why I wanted to see the actual URL of the blob.

Comment: The content-type is: application/octet-stream

Comment: Thanks. Try changing the blob's content type to `video/mp4` and see if that makes any difference.

Comment: I tried that, but it still not working. There is a MD5 tag on the Content.. Could this be a problem?

Comment: It works sometimes in Chrome and working in IE 11. The problem looks like a loading problem in Chrome, and is related to the HTML5 video tag..

Comment: Mp4 is not supported by Chrome anymore. Could they not get a standard please.

Comment: MD5 shouldn't cause this problem. More than likely it looks like an issue with Chrome. What happens in other browsers like Firefox?

Comment: It works in firefax, IE and Safari. Chrome dont support mp4 anymore..

Comment: It works, when I use more than one file in Chrome. Webm videos works in Chrome..