# Azure video streaming to Xamarin

Tags: azure, video, xamarin.forms

We're planning to build a Xamarin app, where you can watch some videos that are hosted on microsoft Azure. Does the azure blob storage support streaming to my mobile app or can i only download the files?
The video urls shouldn't be exposed to public, as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19655868/streaming-video-from-azure-blob-storage).

Has anybody experience in this? I didn't find any reliable infos on the web.

Answer (score 1):

Very important thing here - streaming and live-streaming. If you would like to just upload video files to Azur Blob and access them in the mobile app this is possible. I did tests with .mp4 (I did not test other formats) files and once they were uploaded I could play them in the mobile app without any problems.

You do not have to worry about the access too - you can secure URLs with Shared Access Signature or Storage Account Key.

You can read more about it below (Data Plane Security):

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/storage-security-guide